# How Do I Save All My Camel Errors To A CSV?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a Camel route that reads a CSV file line by line, transforms each line and posts each to a rest api (see  below).

This works when everything is happy.
However, when there are errors from the rest api or even from the CSV parsing I need to group the errors into a single file to go back to the client.
The error file needs to be in the same format as the input with an extra column containing the error so they know what to do.
e.g. if it processes 1000 rows and there are 24 errors, the output should be a CSV with 24 rows in it (plus the header).

How do I trap all the errors in this Camel route and save them into a single output file?

```
public class DataUpload {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //Camel will add the "http" prefix
    String api_url = "localhost:8080";

    File testFile = new File(DataUpload.class.getResource("/InputData.csv").toURI());
    String body = new Scanner(testFile).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
    camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
      public void configure() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        DataFormat jackson = new JacksonDataFormat(objectMapper, CustomDTO.class);
        DataFormat bindy = new BindyCsvDataFormat(CustomRecord.class);

        from("direct:start")
          .log("CSV: ${body}")
          .unmarshal(bindy)
          .split(body())
          .process(new CustomRecordToDtoProcessor())
          .marshal(jackson)
          .log("JSON: ${body}")
          .to("direct:post");

        from("direct:post")
          .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpPost.METHOD_NAME))
          .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON))
          .to("http4://" + api_url + "/api/cars?throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
      }
    });

    camelContext.start();

    ProducerTemplate producer = new DefaultProducerTemplate(camelContext);
    producer.start();
    producer.requestBody("direct:start", body, String.class);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the errors in a `List<customErrorObject>` that you store in a property. Because you're in a split you can add a `.choice()` on error and add the error data to the property in a processor.Then at the end of the route retrieve the property and turn the list to csv and send it to where it needs to go.